# Indy 9 TCP client text encoding

Tags: encoding, tcpclient, indy, indy-9

I have a Delphi 7 app using Indy 9 which connects a `TIdTCPClient` to a `TIdTCPServer` in a Delphi XE2 app using Indy 10.5.

To set the text encoding to UTF-8 in `TIdTCPClient` in Indy 10, I can use this:

```
TCPClient.IOHandler.DefStringEncoding := TIdTextEncoding.UTF8;
```

How can I set the text encoding to UTF-8 in Indy 9, since there is no `DefStringEncoding` property in the `IOHandler`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indy 9 does not support encodings, and also does not support Delphi 2009+ for Unicode.  Everything in Indy 9 assumes/is based on `AnsiString` only.  Strings are transmitted as-is as if they were raw byte arrays.

So, don't send your `AnsiString` data over a connection using ANSI. You can send/receive it as UTF-8 instead. You just have to encode/decode the `AnsiString` data manually, that's all.  Indy 9 will send a UTF-8 encoded `AnsiString` as-is, and read a UTF-8 encoded `AnsiString` as-is. You can then encode/decode the `AnsiString` data to/from UTF-8 as needed in your surrounding code.

For example, your Indy 9 client can do this:

```
IdTCPClient1.WriteLn(UTF8Encode('Some Unicode String Here'));
...
S := UTF8Decode(IdTCPClient1.ReadLn);
```

Then your Indy 10 server can do this:

```
AContext.Connection.IOHandler.DefStringEncoding := TIdTextEncoding.UTF8;
...
S := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn;
...
AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not found a way to set the Encoding UTF8 in Indy 9, then
decided as follows: Knowing what the default encoding in Indy 9 TCPClient is ANSI , I configured the Encoding to ANSI in TCPServer app, converted any UTF8 strings to ANSI before comunications from TCPserver to TCPClient and its all resolved.

Comment: This is not the best answer. It relies on both client and server using the same ANSI encoding, which is not guaranteed if they are running on different machines.

Comment: I agree Remy, I do that because i was in a hurry to resolve, could show me a better method ?